# Why my json.dumps return a string not an array?

Tags: python, django

I'm trying to test out how to send a data from backend to django tempalte

Here is my `views.py`:

```
def index(req):

    labels = ['hello', 'wassup']
    values = []
    
    def chart_label(labels):
        labels1 = []
        for i in labels:
            labels1.append(i)
        return labels1
    
    test = chart_label(labels)
    
    chart_data = {
        'y': json.dumps(test),
    }
    
    return render(req, 'index.html', chart_data)
```

here is my template `index.html`:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
        var y = `{{ y | safe }}`
        console.log(y.length)
</script>
```

I should give me the length is 2 but this is give me 19. Which is every single character in my array?

Comment: Of **course** `json.dumps` returns a `str`... json is a text-based serialization format, you serialized a python object into a string, that's the whole point. Indeed, that's why it'd `dump**s**`, to create a `str` object, normal `json.dump` dumps to a file-like object

Comment: How can I do that ?

Comment: Can you do what? I don't know what you are trying to do. Probably, in javascript, you want to *deserialize* the string into a javascript object... so `JSON.parse(y)`

Comment: so basically i want to send an array from `views.py` to front end how can I do that ?

Comment: You cannot "send an array" across the internet, for the same reason that you cannot "write an array" onto your hard drive. The problem you are encountering is called *serialization*. Whenever data is stored or transported, it can only be raw data. Things like "arrays" do not actually exist anywhere on your computer at any time; they are *interpretations of* the data. What you do is you send data that *represents* an array according to some *format*, and then *parse* that data on the other end.

Comment: On closer examination, it appears that what you are actually trying to do is to *produce Javascript code within your HTML* that will, when run in the client's browser, construct the array, as a JSON literal... yes? That is also a valid approach. Did you try looking at the source of the generated web page? You presumably see quotes around the value used to initialize `y`, and escaping of the quotes within the string... yes?